# How do you create playlists of videos in apple tv

Tags: video, siri, playlist

I need to control videos hands free and open a playlist with siri, but when I create a playlist in itunes and add videos to it, it only appears under music and not under apple tv where the videos are stored. It is empty in music. Alternatively you can suggest an app that supports playlists and siri fast forward/rewind x seconds.